# How to add a new action in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have this in routes.rb

```
map.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.resources :projects, :has_many => :products
end
```

What I would like to is to be able to set the something in the routes.rb file in order for me to use new action in the products controller. Actions added by hand after scaffolding.

I tried something like this

```
 map.namespace :admin do |admin|
   admin.resources :projects, :has_many => :products , :collection => {:plan => :get}
 end
```

plan being my new action in the products controller

Did not work and I have not find any good solutions anywhere. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

As klew already pointed out you probably want a member action and not a collection action.

But before you go this route think if you really needed. adding custom actions is discouraged. You better stay within the constrains of the 7 CRUD operations. The way to do it is to add more controllers :)

For example if you have `users` controller and `groups` controller, then adding person into the group is not `join_group` action in the `users` controller, and not `add_user` action in the `group` controller, its a regular `create` action in `memberships` controller :).

and remember that controllers do not always correspond to models, and models not necessarily correspond to database tables, you can be more flexible.

Back to your case, I think you might want to just add a singleton resource nested inside the project resource like this

```
map.namespace :admin do |admin|
    admin.resources :projects, :has_many_products, :has_one => :plan
end
```

and implement :show action in the plans_controller, which should be mapped to `/admin/projects/:project_id/plan`

Comment: Thank you. The solution I was looking for was different. Simone's solution was what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
map.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.resources :projects, :has_many => :products
end
```

in

```
map.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.resources :projects do |project|
    project.resources :products, :member => { :new_action => :get }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) you have some examples.

Your example should generate urls like: `/admin/projects/plan`. If you want to have url like `/admin/projects/2/plan` then use:

```
map.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.resources :projects, :has_many => :products , :member => {:plan => :get}
end
```

And don't forget to add `plan` method in your `admin/products_controller.rb`:

```
def plan
  ...
end
```

I'm not sure, but probably you will need to restart your server after changing routes to get it working.

Comment: no need to restart in development environment, it will read new routes.rb

Comment: Thank you. What I needed was to be able to have an URL like this:
/admin/projects/2/products/3/plan.